# How to track session in titanium using google analytics?

Tags: ios, titanium-mobile

We can track the session in native iOS or android platforms by setting

tracker.sessionStart = YES;

Is there a similar way to start a manual session in titanium.

Comment: what do you mean by manual session?

Comment: By default, Google Analytics will group hits that are received within 30 minutes of one another into the same session, We can also start new sessions manually at key events in your app's lifecycle.To start a new session, We have to set sessionStart to YES

Answer (score 0):

Titanium doesn't support GA natively (because it has its own analytics), but you can try the [GA module from gitTio](http://gitt.io/component/ti.ga).

Comment: Do we need to include this module directly in our titanium application

Comment: Yes. gitTio has an NPM installer, though. It's pretty straightforward.